# XirSys WebRTC secure connection

Tags: ssl, webrtc, xirsys

- Setting up my simplewebrtc.html video chat room
- Google Chrome browser decides http connections are no longer supported (https only)
- I get my SSL certificate - and end up with this problem...

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myURL.com/xsdk-master/examples/simplewebrtc.php?roomName=767' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://endpoint02.uswest.xirsys.com:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1450578074425'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Seems self-explanatory I need to use a secure endpoint on XirSys end, but
I tried getting in touch with experts@xirsys.com - and they're out until December 28th, 2015. Anybody know if a secure endpoint exists? Please any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? Same issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the port on the endpoint to 443. The 8080 port you are using won't work on a secure page.

Regards,
Lee

Comment: You mean you just need to change the port in the url? Also add https maybe? That's it? Has this been confirmed?

Comment: Sorry for not testing first. It did work for me. It should be marked as the accepted answer. Thanks @lee-sylvester.